# Expressing A Person's Height

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I would like to express a person's height in German. For example, if I wanted to say, I am six feet tall, I think I could say:

> Ich bin sechs Fuß Höhe.

Or if I wanted to say that my girlfriend is 5 and a half feet tall I would say:

> Meine Freundin ist fünf und hälfte Fuß Höhe.

Is that correct?

Comment: The imperial sizes also need to be translated to metric ones (centimeter probably), same applies for weight (kilogramm). Otherwise the typical  German addressee will have to resort to his/her unit converter.

Comment: "Fuß" is a part of body that we use to walk. It is not a unit anybody uses who speaks German. We have "Meter", "Zentimeter" and so on.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast It used to be. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fusz#Bedeutung4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not.

When talking about a person's height you have to use "Größe".

> "Ich bin 185 cm groß."
>
> "Meine Freundin ist 170 cm groß."

"Höhe" is used for things, but not for people. For example:

> Welche Höhe hat dieser Baum?

would translate to

> What's the height of this tree?

Comment: It would be more natural to say: "Wie hoch ist dieser Baum?", although the other phrase is not wrong.

Comment: Could you add that the "groß" is often skipped,as is the "cm" or "meter"... "Ich bin eins achtzig" That's idiomatic too.

Comment: @MartinPeters That's true. However I feel like using the noun in both languages simplifies comparing the sentences.

Comment: You would probably not ask "Welche Höhe hat dieser Baum?", but "Wie hoch ist dieser Baum?".

Answer (score 13):

If you use feet, most people in Germany will have no clue how much that is. Always use the metric system.

> Ich bin eins achtzig groß. (1 Meter und 80 Zentimeter.)
> Meine Freundin ist einen Meter fünfundsechzig groß.

Answer (score 0):

> Meine Freundin ist fünf und hälfte Fuß Höhe.

When talking about half of a value, use "~einhalb" like e.g.

- diese Melone wiegt dreieinhalb Kilo (3.5 kg)
- dieses Kind ist eineinhalb Meter groß (1.5 m)

Comment: This is correct, but just a small part of the answer. See also the other answers regarding feet vs cm --- you probably don't need to use "hundertsechzigeinhalb Zentimeter". stackexchange is not a discussion forum. Please take the tour, and only post new and complete answers, not answers to other answers.

Comment: maybe make a mention that your second example would be phrased "anderthalb" meaning eineinhalb in a good portion of cases.